# huge amount of data is written to mail.log once every minute

Tags: ubuntu, email, postfix, log-files

I'm on Ubuntu server and a huge amount of lines is written to my /var/log/mail.log once every minute. The lines look like:

```
  Mar 11 17:39:08 Ubuntu-1010-maverick-32-minimal postfix/qmgr[1085]: 75A8B17150: from=<root@example.org>, size=769, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
  Mar 11 17:39:08 Ubuntu-1010-maverick-32-minimal postfix/qmgr[1085]: 7F70417129: from=<>, size=2900, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
  Mar 11 17:39:08 Ubuntu-1010-maverick-32-minimal postfix/qmgr[1085]: 7BD0616D9D: from=<>, size=2819, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
  Mar 11 17:39:08 Ubuntu-1010-maverick-32-minimal postfix/qmgr[1085]: 7A10716D88: from=<>, size=2841, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
  Mar 11 17:39:08 Ubuntu-1010-maverick-32-minimal postfix/qmgr[1085]: 7AA5C107FC3: from=<root@example.org>, size=778, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
  Mar 11 17:39:08 Ubuntu-1010-maverick-32-minimal postfix/qmgr[1085]: 7462F433F8: from=<>, size=2870, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
```

or

```
  Mar 11 17:54:26 Ubuntu-1010-maverick-32-minimal postfix/error[3500]: 729BE4CF6C: to=<root@example.org>, orig_to=<root>, relay=none, delay=134965, delays=134937/29/0/0, dsn=4.4.1, status=deferred (delivery temporarily suspended: connect to example.org[2606:2800:220:1:248:1893:25c8:1946]:25: Network is unreachable)
  Mar 11 17:54:26 Ubuntu-1010-maverick-32-minimal postfix/error[3488]: 73FAB4D467: to=<root@example.org>, orig_to=<root>, relay=none, delay=55045, delays=55016/29/0/0, dsn=4.4.1, status=deferred (delivery temporarily suspended: connect to example.org[2606:2800:220:1:248:1893:25c8:1946]:25: Network is unreachable)
  Mar 11 17:54:26 Ubuntu-1010-maverick-32-minimal postfix/error[3504]: 7B460870F2: to=<root@example.org>, orig_to=<root>, relay=none, delay=256705, delays=256676/29/0/0, dsn=4.4.1, status=deferred (delivery temporarily suspended: connect to example.org[2606:2800:220:1:248:1893:25c8:1946]:25: Network is unreachable)
```

The problem is - neither I nor my cronjob are trying to send anything. So what's happening here?

Comment: Looks like you have multiple mails stuck in the queue. And once they eventually time out and bounce, the bounces get stuck in the queue as well. Might it be some of your outgoing mails are for recipients on IPv6-only domains?

Comment: Yes, there were more than 40000 mails in the queue. It seems that some process tries to send a mail to root@example.org and my next step is to find that application

Comment: `example.org` doesn't have any MX record, but it is standard behavior to fall back to behave as if the MX record pointed to the domain itself in case there is no MX record. However connections to port 25 on `example.org` appear to consistently time out. So any such mails would stay in the queue for as long as the mail server is configured to retry (which is usually a few days). It is odd that your log lines only show IPv6 attempts and no IPv4 attempts. But maybe you just didn't include those lines in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem re-appeared. Therefore I cannot accept user208998's answer anymore.

The cause was cron. One of my cronjobs exited unsuccessfully. I didn't notice that because the actual task was performed correctly. Because I didn't set the `MAILTO` environment variable, cron tried to inform user root by email. For unknown reasons cron thinks my host name is "example.org".

Information for others with similar problems: Finding the problem's origin was a coincident. You can determine the process which tries sending the mail and that of course is "postfix". However, I wasn't able to determine the process which made postfix to send the mail.

Answer (score 3):

There is something in your mail spool that you are unaware of, and postfix is attempting to use ipv6 to transfer the email to some remote server, but that connection is consistently failing.  Postfix prefers using ipv6 if it is available on the host, but your local network, or the remote host may not support ipv6 yet.  I had this issue on one of our internal servers when we first started rolling out ipv6 on our office network.

To prevent postfix from using ipv6, update the postfix configuration to set a variable thusly:

```
inet_protocols = ipv4
```

and then restart postfix with

```
service postfix restart
```

Postfix will now use only ipv4 connections.  On Ubuntu, this is in the **/etc/postfix/main.cf** file.

A lot of applications and services are setup to send email to root about errors, and it appears that there is at least one such email on your server.  To see pending email, use

```
mailq
```

Comment: Other mail servers are entirely capable of trying each of the possible destination addresses one by one until they find one which works. I would expect postfix to do that as well. So disabling IPv6 would make those log lines disappear, but it wouldn't solve the root cause of the problem. Whatever messages are stuck in the queue will not have better chances of getting delivered if you disable IPv6.

Comment: The same errors appear in /var/log/mail.info until january, therefore i think the problem is not ipv6 related. Your answer was very helpful, though. Even if it doesn't solve my problem completely it answers my question.

Comment: I forgot to mention in my comment that entries in mail.info had ipv4 addresses - that's why i think it's not ipv6 related

Comment: The servers I was working with at the time all had IPv4 IPs, and we'd recently enabled IPv6, Postfix, in my server, was failing to deliver 75% of the email messages in its queue; all attempts to connect over ipv6 failed and shoved the messages back into the queue; only the attempts over IPv4 worked.  part of your log specifically shows failing IPv6 connections.  That's why I bothered to answer.

Answer (score 0):

In my case was fail2ban that was sending mails to root every minute because of bruteforce attempts, so in this cases take a look at /var/mail/ directory too and see if you find something bigger than it's should be.